# Turn phone with an IR blaster into wifi enabled IR hub

Tags: android, iot

I have two phones

Phone A: I use it daily

Phone B : Has IR blaster, Android nougat. I use it to control my Tv volume and Airconditioner

I want my phone B to control AC as I send signal from phone A when I am not around.

Tried remote applications like TeamViewer and airdroid but they were lagging on nougat(IR phone)